# Linear endomorphism fixing an affine hyperplane not passing through the origin is the identity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be an affine hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$ not passing through the origin and let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map such that $f(p)=p$ for any $p \in H$. Show that $f$ is the identity of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Affine hyperplane can be written as
$$
H=\{ a+p : p \in H_0 \}
$$
where $a$ is a point in $H$, and $H_0$ is a hyperplane passing through origin.

Then $H_0$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\neq 0$ is not on $H_0$. 
Thus, $a$ and a basis for $H_0$ together make a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $a \in H$, we have $f(a)=a$. Also, $f(a+p)=a+p$ for all $p\in H_0$. Moreover, by linearity of $f$, we have
$$
f(a+p)= f(a)+f(p),
$$
Thus, $f(a)+ f(p)= a+p$.

This yields $f(p)=p$ for all $p\in H_0$.

Therefore, for any element $b\in B$, we have $f(b) = b$. This means that $f$ is an identity on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how have you proved that $f(a)=a$? There is no hypothesis on the behavior of $f$ on $a$. I tried to show that $f: H_0 \to H_0$ is the identity map, but I proved only that the restriction of $f$ to $H_0$ is a linear endomorphism.

Comment: $a$ is a point in $H$ and $f$ fixes every point in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider $H$ and three not-aligned points  in it. We call them $P_0, P_1, P_2$. We know that $3$ not-aligned points generate an affine coordinate system.

Now we call this map $\phi \in Aff(H)$. We have that $\phi(P_i)=P_i \ \forall i_1^3$. But we know that an affinity is completely determined by what it does on a coordinate system. So it must be the identity.